# i am beginner and having problem with this!. I want output to print in seperate subLists in the mainList only one time

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Function to count how many Sublistslists are inside a List
def Sublist_counter(l):
    count = 0
    for c in l:
        if type(c) == list:
            count+=1
    return count


#Main List for storing sublists
l_main = [ ] 

#Extra lists used inside for loop for storing data
l_extra = [ ]

n = int(input("Enter number of Lists : ")) 
  
for i in range(0, n): 
    list1 = int(input("Enter number of elements in first List : ")) 
    for j in range(0,list1):
        ele = [input()]         
        l_extra.append(ele)
    l_main.append(l_extra)
         

print("...You have entered the following Lists with data inside the main List...")
print(f" {l_main}" )
print(f"Number of Sublists are :{Sublist_counter(l_main)}")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzBEz.png

Comment: replace `ele = [input()]` with `ele = input()`. The extra `[ ]` is causing the brackets inside the list.

Comment: I already tried by replacing it like the way you said but still, the output is like :                                
Enter the number of elements in List1:  1
1
Enter the number of elements in List2 :  3
2
3
1
...You have entered the following Lists with data inside the main List...
 [['1', '2', '3', '1'], ['1', '2', '3', '1']]

Comment: I found 2 errors in your code. Fixed them. See my answer below for the changes to your code.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and desired output. That will help fix the code (if you need additional help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor changes to your code and it works perfectly.

The changes I made to your code.

```
#Extra lists used inside for loop for storing data
l_extra = [ ]
```

These two lines, I moved them inside the for loop `for i in range(0, n):`. Why? You need to reset the list every time. Otherwise, all your values will get added into the list. Your final list will look a bit wacky.

The second change is to remove the `[ ]` bracket from `ele = [input()]` Instead, I made it `ele = input()` That way it just accepts the input values and appends to your `l_extra` list

To help you figure out which list you are entering the value, I changed your input statement a bit. It has been updated to

`list1 = int(input("Enter number of elements in List " + str(i+1) + " : "))`

Below is the working code.

```
def Sublist_counter(l):
    count = 0
    for c in l:
        if type(c) == list:
            count+=1
    return count


#Main List for storing sublists
l_main = [ ] 

n = int(input("Enter number of Lists : ")) 
  
for i in range(0, n):
    #Extra lists used inside for loop for storing data
    l_extra = [ ]
    
    list1 = int(input("Enter number of elements in List " + str(i+1) + " : ")) 
    for j in range(0,list1):
        ele = input()       
        l_extra.append(ele)
    l_main.append(l_extra)
         

print("...You have entered the following Lists with data inside the main List...")
print(f" {l_main}" )
print(f"Number of Sublists are :{Sublist_counter(l_main)}")
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Enter number of Lists : 3
Enter number of elements in List 1 : 4
Apple
Banana
Salt
Peach
Enter number of elements in List 2 : 3
Morning
Afternoon
Evening
Enter number of elements in List 3 : 5
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
...You have entered the following Lists with data inside the main List...
 [['Apple', 'Banana', 'Salt', 'Peach'], ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'], ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']]
Number of Sublists are :3
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and for solving the problem.

Comment: dont forget to upvote if the answer solved your problem.